# Child route shows parent's html component below it

Tags: angular

Inside the Dashboard Component I have My Profile Component inside it. When I go to `dashboard/my-profile` page then  my-profile works! is shown as it is the code inside my-profile html component but down below the dashboard html page (component) is rendered.
I was looking to just show the my-profile page (component) when someone goes to that route. Am am I doing wrong.

In app routing ts file

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MyProfileComponent } from './dashboard/my-profile/my-profile.component'
const routes: Routes = [
     { 
         path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], resolve: {"key": ProfileDetailsResolverService}, 
         children: [
             {path: 'my-profile', component: MyProfileComponent }
         ]
        },
];
```

App module ts file

```
 import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
    import { MyProfileComponent } from './dashboard/my-profile/my-profile.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   DashboardComponent,
   MyProfileComponent
```

first line of dashboard component html file

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App Component

```
<div>
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of putting <router-outlet></router-outlet> in dashboard add it in a appcomponent html then load your route

Comment: app component already has `<router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>`I remove router outlet from dashboard's html and when i go to my-profile it just renders dashboards html

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from the DashboardComponent html template.

**Routing**

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MyProfileComponent } from './dashboard/my-profile/my-profile.component'
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
    path: 'dashboard', 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    resolve: {"key": ProfileDetailsResolverService}, 
    children: [
        {
             path: '',
             component: DashboardComponent,
             pathMatch: 'full' // if it won't work try remove/add this line
        },
        {
            path: 'my-profile', 
            component: MyProfileComponent
        }
    ]
}
];
```

Comment: So you are setting the first child as the index which is dashboard (parent component). It works with or with path match. It works with or without  pathMatch: 'full'

Answer (score 0):

Well when the router-outlet ist not the only line there will always other stuff be rendered when you configure child-routes and nav to them.

when you want to seperate that you can configure some kind of routing like that:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], resolve: {"key": ProfileDetailsResolverService}, 
    children: [
      {path: 'index', component: DashboardIndexComponent },
      {path: 'my-profile', component: MyProfileComponent },
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'index' },
  ]}
];
```

and remove the other html from your DashboardComponent so that it is only a routing component.